# Use list(map(model_to_dict, queryset_list)) do not map the createtime and updatetime fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Test04 Model, and I give `ctime` and `uptime` fields.

```
class Test04(models.Model):
    testTime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

But when I use the `list(map(model_to_dict, queryset_list))` method to convert the queryset to dictionary, I find the ctime and uptime do not convert:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

print (models.Test04.objects.all())


all =models.Test04.objects.all()

print (all[0].ctime)  # 2017-09-26 07:49:02.012489+00:00

print (list(map(model_to_dict, all))) # [{u'id': 1, 'testTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 7, 49, 1, 973016, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {u'id': 2, 'testTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 8, 3, 24, 665944, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {u'id': 3, 'testTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 0, 12, 12, 683801, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {u'id': 4, 'testTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 0, 12, 43, 2169, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {u'id': 5, 'testTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 8, 13, 16, 164395, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {u'id': 6, 'testTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 0, 14, 8, 812063, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {u'id': 7, 'testTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 0, 15, 32, 945493, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

In the last line's output, you see there is no `ctime` and `uptime` in every dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would do this. Django includes a queryset method to return dicts: `Test04.objects.values()`.

`model_to_dict` is an internal utility method meant for converting a model instance for use in a form, which is why it's found in the forms module. Fields that are populated automatically, like your two datetimes, are not included in forms because there is no reason to edit them.